# Error on trying to match array with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to to match the user input to an array, but don't seem to get anything as a response. Any help is great. Thank you.

```
`#import json module to read json file
import json

#open then read file and close file
fin=open("weather-data.json","r")
json_string=fin.read()
fin.close()

#Json to python dictionary 
array=json.loads(json_string)

#User input
desired_month=input("Input a month number 1 -5:")
desired_day=input("Pick a day in the month:")

#matching day and month to dic.
for d in array:
    if desired_month==d["month"] and desired_day==d["day"]:
        print (d[{"high"}],d[{"low"}])

`
```

weather-data.json has the following format:

```
[
    {
        "year": 2014,
        "month": 1,
        "day": 1,
        "high": 22,
        "low": 16,
        "precip": 0.25
    },
    {
        "year": 2014,
        "month": 1,
        "day": 2,
        "high": 21,
        "low": 10,
        "precip": 0.22
    }, ...
]
```

Comment: Can you post `weather-data.json` to help us reproduce your problem?

Comment: I receive no error message, but no output either. I'll post weather-data.json. Sorry i forgot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are storing the `desired_month` and the `desired_day` as strings, whereas the JSON files stores them as integers. Because of that, your comparison between the desired values and the values stored in the JSON is always going to evaluate to `False`, and the high and low temperatures are never going to be printed.

The secondary problem is that there was a Python syntax typo when printing the high and low temperatures. The syntax for accessing the value of a dictionary given a key is `d["high"]`, and not `d[{"high"}]`.

Here is a modified version with a few corrections (`weather.py`):

```
import json

# Load JSON
with open("weather-data.json") as weather_data_file:
    weather_list = json.load(weather_data_file)

# Get user inputs (as strings) and convert them integers for later comparison
desired_month = int(input("Input a month number 1 -5:"))
desired_day = int(input("Pick a day in the month:"))

# matching day and month to content of JSON file
for weather_entry in weather_list:
    if desired_month == weather_entry["month"] and desired_day == weather_entry["day"]:
        print(weather_entry["high"], weather_entry["low"])
```

Example output for the program:

```
➜ python weather.py
Input a month number 1 -5:2
Pick a day in the month:25
22 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So, for future reference, anytime a .json file is imported the values are integers? Also I attempted to change my code by changing the user input into integers, but it still wouldn't return an output?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback J. Doe. I updated my answer. There was a second problem with the syntax for accessing the weather entry dictionary. I also added an example at the end to show the values that I used (2 for month and 25 for day).

Comment: Thank you so much Pierre. I really appreciate the explanations and examples. I still have a lot to learn. I was stuck for for a long time on that because I was receiving no error code and didn't know the .json imports as integers